# Multiple explanatory variables using GAM in R?

Tags: r, gam

I'm pretty new to R, and I'm trying to use the `mgcv::gam` function to model my data but it has a lot of explanatory variables. I know that with a regular linear regression model you could just use `.` to account for the variables, but does that work with GAM as well? Or is there another shorthand way to include all the variables in a data set?

Say that I have explanatory variables `a` through `z` and I want a prediction equation

```
y ~ s(a) + s(b) + ... + s(z)
```

Is there an easier way to denote this?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are going to do this (there must be a lot of variables if you don't want to type them out) then it suggest to me that you should also be using `select = TRUE` in the `gam()` call and know what the implications of doing this are.

Comment: Also, I hope you have a *lot* of data because adding 26 smooths to the model will require estimating of the order ~240 coeficients plus selecting 26 smoothness paraneters plus 26 more for the extra penalty from `select = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a quite `y ~ .` to encompass that, as far as I know. However, suppose that you want to use all variables. Then you can use `paste` and formula to perform the same task. Say that you are using the `mtcars` dataframe, and your `y` variable is `mpg`.

Then the following serves:

```
mgcv::gam(
  as.formula(
    paste0(
      "mpg ~ s(", 
      setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg") %>% paste0(collapse = ") + s("),
      ")"
    )
  ),
  data = mtcars
)
```

So the point is the `collapse` argument, and shutting the parentheses. In your application, that'll be

```
mgcv::gam(
  as.formula(paste0("y ~ s(", letters %>% paste0(collapse = ") + s("), ")")),
  data = df
)
```